# How to open command on second tab in bash terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, tail

So I am writing a script and I want to export a log but open the tail command in another tab.

So far this is what I have come up with in BASH.

```
./configure &> log.configure.txt && gnome-terminal --tab
```

(What goes here for tail to automatically open in the next tab.?)

example: `export TEST_BED=test &&  gnome-terminal  echo $TEST_BED`
Doesn't work but this is what I am trying to get at.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402152/gnome-terminal-new-tab-with-alias-as-command-to-execute/17982997#answer-58157260

```
export TEST_BED=test && gnome-terminall --tab -- $SHELL -c "echo $TEST_BED; read -p 'press any key to continue'"
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to do what I want it to do. 

I want to run my configure script in terminal tab1 and then in terminal tab 2 I want the tail command to be showing what's going on in the log file.

Comment: ./configure &> log.configure.txt && gnome-terminal --tab tail -f log.configure.txt

Is what I am trying to do

Comment: Perhaps run the command in the background and then just follow the log with tail? You can also redirect output to stdout and to a file (so the output is logged and also you see it in the terminal "in the usual way"): example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout. I've never tried to have a tab opened by the script ... so those are my ideas without having a second tab involved. But in principle if you can open a second tab then all you have to do is execute the tail command in the second tab and it should work.

Comment: this seems to work sort of ... `xfce4-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'tail log.txt; read -n1'"` ... based on example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158434/open-gnome-terminal-with-several-tabs-and-execute-a-few-commands-in-every-tab (I am using Xubuntu hence xfce4). It's not clear if tail will continue to read new output or not though - needs testing as my file is just a static log file. Seems that the final read command is to keep the window open ... as explained in the link above ... and further links there about -e being deprecated (ah scripting ... love it!)

Comment: @WillH doesn't it work?
`./configure &> log.configure.txt && gnome-terminal --tab $SHELL -c "tail -f log.configure.txt"`

Comment: @topsail Yes, in my ubuntu 20.04 environment, gnome-terminal does not support -e option, it says use --. And tail -f works. I tested this command `ls && gnome-terminal --tab -- $SHELL -c "tail -f /var/log/syslog; read -p 'press any key to exit' -n 1;"` and read message never appears